# MySQL How to select minimum value for duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[From following 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMZUw.png)

I want to select minimum value for each 'sid'.
Output be like

```
S102 | 27800.00,
S101 | 90000.50,
S103 | 250000.00,
S104 | 15000.00,
S105 | 7500.75
```

Comment: Where is your query? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use group by:

```
select sid, min(o_amt) from orders group by sid
```

Comment: @ZafranUllah Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.